# Whenever I try to use setfill manipulator in C++, it just displays blanks

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my code for just trying to fill the spaces with `*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << setw(10) << setfill('*');
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

However the program just displays blanks, in other words it just displays an empty line!

So please, what's wrong with it?

Note: I tried to compile on VS 2015 and GCC 4.9.2 and got the same result.

Comment: It fills up field outputs.

Comment: You didn't output anything; try `cout << "";`.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is the reason that your manipulators are ignored:

> Inserts a newline character into the output sequence os and flushes it
>   as if by calling `os.put(os.widen('\n'))` followed by `os.flush()`.

The `put` call in the first part is the culprit. You can reduce your problem to it, as evidenced by the following experiment which will only write `x` to the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('*');
    std::cout.put('x');
}
```

The problem is that [`put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) performs unformatted output:

> Behaves as an UnformattedOutputFunction.

The fix is easy: Just don't use `std::endl`. Use `"\n"`. **You should prefer `"\n"` anyway.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << setw(10) << setfill('*');
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This will generate the desired output:

```
*********
```

And while we're at it:

- Avoid `using namespace std`.
- Don't use `system("pause")`.
- The `return 0` in `main` is redundant.

Comment: While I don't understand the put part, I'm just a pudding programmer, I get that the problems lies in endl, however I am not entirely sure what differentiates endl from '\n'.

Comment: Why avoid using namespace std? I just feel like you know typing less?
System("pause") is only used here for testing purposes as the console just flash in and out in less than a second.
Correct me if I am wrong, if the main function is of type int shouldn't it return something?

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyway I am forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to something to std::cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << setw(10) << setfill('*') << "" << std::endl;
    cout << setw(10) << setfill('*') << 1 << std::endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as for the other answer: A linebreak *is* something, but `std::endl`causes the format manipulators to be ignored.

Comment: Why does line break causes format manipulators to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write something before filling with "*" :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "test" ;
    cout << setw(10) << setfill('*');
    cout << "test" ;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He *does* write something. A linebreak is most definitely something. The problem is that the linebreak is written as if with a call to `put`, which ignores the format manipulators.

Comment: Aha I get it now.